# Don't display incomplete orders in Control Panel

Tags: expresso-store

Is there a way to not show the incomplete orders in the Store control panel? Currently it shows ever cart created, which adds up to quite a bit of not so useful info to delete.

Answer (score 0):

Short of modifying the core files to not show incomplete orders your best bet would be to use the Order Status dropdown to change the status to your successful order status which by default is "New".

Comment: Is this a recent change? Because I don't remember seeing incomplete orders in store v2.3, although I see from the release notes it has been a feature since 1.5...